# I cannot move a servo manually

Tags: pwm, servo

My servo is classic SG90. I connected +5V and gnd correctly to a dc power supply. Then I connected output of a signal generator which generates 0-5 V pulses at 50Hz (checked by oscilloscope).

I know that the duty cycle determines the position of a servo motor. I can vary the duty cycle between %20 and %80 from the settings of the signal generator and I can observe that pulse is changing accordingly via the oscilloscope. However, servo does not responds. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the GND of the signal generator connected to the GND of the servo?

Comment: THe servo specs indicate 1 ~2ms which is 5 to 10% at 5V , otherwise 0V for PWM with 20ms cycle =50Hz

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes all gnd's are common at one point.

Comment: RC servos use the time of the pulse width, not the duty cycle (ratio between on timeand period). The valid range is 1ms to 2 ms for a high pulse with 1.5ms being the center. They dont care about actual frequency too much as long as they get a high pulse often enough so that they do not "forget" their position.

Comment: @DKNguyen so you say that 250 Hz %25 to %50 duty cycle will do the job?

Comment: @muyustan Well, there is a limit to how frequent and infrequent a servo can accept. A good analog servo might be able to accept 250Hz and a digital servo should have no problem, but your typical analog servo can't. You could always give it a shot but watch for overheating if it does work since more frequent motion updates can also means more power. This should not be an issue with digital servos since they update the motion separately from the input pulse whereas in an analog servo the motor is directly updated by the pulse.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have tried and it worked actually. But I dont know whether sg90 is digital or analog servo.

Comment: @muyustan That's an analog servo based on size and cost alone and a cheap one. You usually know when you're buying a digital servo. Honestly, I'm rather surprised it can accept 250Hz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, your PWM may be way too high.  A typical hobby servo might need a signal at 50-60 Hz.  Let's take 50Hz as an example.  That means that every 0.020 second, it might need a pulse around 1.5ms (0.0015s) to seek "center" position.  So, that equates to about 7% duty cycle.  Try a lower PWM range to get pulses of 0.0010s to 0.0020s at 50Hz.

And as the comment suggests, the GND connections must be common.

Comment: Don't any of the duty cycle values between 20 and 80 correspond any position?

Comment: No, they don't. That's way out of spec for the servo.

Comment: @DaveTweed thanks, it was my silliness, now I checked the specs and you are right even 4 ms(%20 dutycycle) was greater than 180° position. So is there any way that I can get valid duration of pulses considering my signal generator does not allow between 0-20 and 80-100 duty cycles.

Comment: There are many examples of 555-based and MCU-based test circuits for servos on the Web. This is also something that an Arduino can easily do for you.

Comment: @DaveTweed yes microcontroller is a nice and realistic solution, just dont have one available at now and just doing some trials not a big concern. But when it didnt work I just wondered why. Thanks again.